# Функция для авторизации на PHP

Tags: php, функции, авторизация

Cтараюсь сделать авторизацию на сайте и возникла проблема. Пытаюсь писать нормальный код и убрать не нужное повторение кода. Проблема в php-коде, а именно с обработкой login и password, как сделать это более оптимально(использовать меньше кода для их обработки)?

HTML-код:

```html
<form action="<?$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
 <h1>Вход</h1>
 <label>Логин <input type="text" name="login" id="login"></label>
 <label>Пароль <input type="password" name="password" id="password"></label>
 <button type="submit" name="auth_button" id="auth_button">Вход</button>
 <p id="error"><?echo $error_1?></p>
</form>
```

PHP-код:

```
require_once('bd/bd.php');
if (isset($_POST['auth_button'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['login']) || !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $login = strip_tags($_POST['login']);
        $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
        $login = mysql_escape_string($login);
        $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
        $password = mysql_escape_string($password);
    }
    else{
        unset($_POST['login'], $_POST['password']);
        $error_1 = "Не заполнен логин или пароль";
    }
}
```

Comment: Не надо таких манипуляций с логином и паролем делать (да и вообще со всеми другими данными) как вы тут показали. Я про обработку функциями strip_tags(), htmlspecialchars() и mysql_escape_string(). Для работы с базой использовать только **PDO и подготовленные выражения**. При выводе данных пользователю использовать обработку переменных через **htmlspecialchars()**. Ни каких функций **mysql_**, их уже нет в php7!

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: trim() сделать можно, иначе потом могут быть недоразумения))

Comment: Как сказал первый комментёр:), не надо обрабатывать данные до записи в БД. Лучше потом при выводе это сделать.